# URL Redirect based on client logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

How do I redirect url based on register client in c# .net or asp.net 4.0. For example if client registers as "client1" and our website is www.mycompany.com for every page client proceeds should get www.client1.mycompany.com.

More detailed example:

For example another client created is Client2.
The pages i have created in general is like 
"www.mycompany.com/product.aspx"
"www.mycompany.com/categories.aspx"
 should be shown as
"www.client2.mycompany.com/product.aspx" and 
www.client2.mycompany.com/categories.aspx" respectively

I have searched on web and found for static pages or using Gloabal.asax during startup of application but haven't found any thing after user logged in.

Comment: Why would you do it that way and not just use a querystring parameter or session cookie to delineate user groups?

Comment: I feel sorry for those users when using their site.  Giving a URL to another person would be all messed up...

Comment: I want to do something like zendesk where if some client comes. I will give them separate urls. Like "www.Company1.mycompany.com" for company1. In above example please consider client name instead of user